# apple-touch-icon change icon only after restarting iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, apple-touch-icon

I have web application which works in standalone mode (launched from home screen) on devices. What I need is when the icon was changed it would be changed on my device. So on the page i have:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href=@UrlExtensions.GetIconUrl(Url, "76×76", Model.IconUrlFromApi) />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76×76" href=@UrlExtensions.GetIconUrl(Url, "76×76", Model.IconUrlFromApi) />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120×120" href=@UrlExtensions.GetIconUrl(Url, "120×120", Model.IconUrlFromApi) />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152×152" href=@UrlExtensions.GetIconUrl(Url, "152×152", Model.IconUrlFromApi) />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href=@UrlExtensions.GetIconUrl(Url, "precomposed", Model.IconUrlFromApi) />
<link rel="icon" href=@UrlExtensions.GetIconUrl(Url, "152×152", Model.IconUrlFromApi) type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href=@UrlExtensions.GetIconUrl(Url, "48x48", Model.IconUrlFromApi) />
```

And the icon changes after running the application and then restarting iPhone.
Is it possible to do so icon would change without restaring iPhone?

BTW My application uses application cache.. maybe this could cause the problem